# Magento store codes redirect to 404

Tags: php, magento, mod-rewrite, magento-1.8

Magento 1.8.1, I set the store codes to represent each country and when I navigate to them using website.com/store/us I get a 404 error - all of my products are enabled and set to this store.

What may help is - this was working perfectly on another server, I recently uploaded the database into a fresh installation of Magento (both were the same version). Everything works except when I click the 'add to cart' button from the product list view it redirects to the default store code it gives me a 404 error.

All products seem to redirect to a 404 as well.

Comment: Which Magento 404 page?  There are many (http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages), and each comes from a different source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. The new server didn't have the necessary folders from the last in the store root. (EG: us, uk, etc)
These folders need to there with their own index.php & .htaccess.